# Cocoa - Read content of a file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, filepath, readfile

I'm just trying to read the content of a text file that is in my project in the main folder.

```
// file name is "logs"
// it returns nil
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logs" ofType:nil];


// file name is "logs.txt"
// it returns nil
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logs" ofType:@"txt"];
```

Questions:

- How can I get the path to a file that
  is included in my project?
- How can I get the path to the root
  folder of my project?

Comment: When you build your project, are the resource files (logs, logs.txt) being copied to the Resources directory? Note that this should happen in the **build** directory.

Comment: You need to make sure that those files are listed in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase of our target. In Xcode 4, click your root project in Project Navigator > click your target > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources.

Comment: why don't you post that as an answer? I added the file to my target and that fixed the problem. thanks

Comment: Heheh, I was just doing that! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that a file is present in your project directory doesn’t mean the file will be copied to the corresponding target application bundle. You need to add the file to the target via the Copy Bundle Resources build phase.

In order to inspect and edit the list of files that are copied to the bundle directory in Xcode 4:

- Click your root project in Project Navigator
- Click your target
- Select Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources

Note: when you add a file to the project via Xcode, the add file dialog gives you a choice of adding that file to a target so that you don’t need to do these steps later.